# Pantalla en blanco React Navigation

Tags: react-native, reactjs, react-navigation

Llamo desde un componente a otro que tiene React Navigation, directamente funciona, pero al poner el View que contenga a este componente aparece la pantalla en blanco.

Ejemplo:

FUNCIONA:

```
render() {
    return (
        <RutasNoAutenticadas/>

    );
}
```

NO FUNCIONA:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View
        <RutasNoAutenticadas/>
      </View>

    );
}
```

Y requiero la segunda parte (la que no funciona), debido a que quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.props.usuario? <RutasAutenticadas/>: <RutasNoAutenticadas/>}
        </View>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no es recomendable que uses condiciones ternarias dentro del JSX, yo te recomiendo que hagas una funcion y la llames desde el `render()`, por ejemplo:

```
obtenerRutas = () => (
  this.props.usuario ? <RutasAutenticadas /> : <RutasNoAutenticadas />;
)

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.obtenerRutas()}
        </View>

    );
}
```

Respecto a la duda del por que no funciona. Necesitaria un poco mas de contexto y codigo para ver como tienes implementada la navegacion.